# SQL Cursor to loop through a column and determine if the range of a sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, range, sequence

I'm attempting to setup a cursor to loop through a column in my table and determine if the sequence has ended. If the sequence has ended, i want to output the start and end values. 
For example:

```
 00001  
 00002
 00003
 00004   -- End here and output 1-4
 00007
 00008
 00009   -- End here and output 7-9 
 00011
 00012
 00013   -- End here and output 11-13
```

Im very new to cursors but i believe this is how you start dealing with them:

```
DECLARE @Product bigint
DECLARE @ProductId nvarchar(100)

DECLARE @ProductCursor CURSOR

SET @ProductCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    Products.Product,
    Products.ProductId
FROM Products

OPEN @ProductCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @ProductCursor INTO
@Product,
@ProductId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    --Do something
    SELECT 'aaa'

    FETCH NEXT FROM @ProductCursor INTO
    @Product,
    @ProductId

END

CLOSE @ProductCursor
DEALLOCATE @ProductCursor
```

My thinking is that i should loop through the values from 1 to 13 and check that the value that went before it equals the current value. Such if we are on 0004, we should hold the previous value (00003) in  variable, add 1 and check to see if it equals the current value (00004). If it does not, we then have to end the current sequence and output the start and end values. Im not entirely sure how do this, maybe set up a counter ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: Is the point of the exercise to practice using cursors?

Comment: Yes, I've got part way through my example, just need some additional pointers in order for me to continue

Comment: You are using Ms SQL server cursor syntax.  Here MySQL Cursor syntax : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html